# SwiftUI CPU High Usage on Real-Time ForEach View Updating (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, metalkit, swiftui-foreach

So I have a view and I am computing the amplitude of an audio file and then passing it to a view to graph it and it changes in real-time. The problem is that the graph gets so laggy after few seconds and CPU usage gets maximized and literally everything kind of freezes.
Is there any way to render the view using GPU instead of the CPU in SwiftUI macOS?

I am updating the values for amplitudes in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` and sending an `NSNotification`.

[image: SwiftUI Graph Real Time Updating]

This is the file I am calling when I want to show the graphs

```
struct TimeDomain: View {
    
    @Binding var manager: AVManager
    @State var pub = DSPNotification().publisherPath()
    @State var amps =  [Double]()
    
    var body: some View {

        AmplitudeVisualizer(amplitudes: $amps).frame(height: 300)
            .onReceive(pub) { (output) in
                self.amps = manager.amplitudes
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.amps = manager.amplitudes
            }
            .drawingGroup()
    }
}
```

and the file for `AmplitudeVisualizer.swift`

```
struct AmplitudeVisualizer: View {
    
    @Binding var amplitudes: [Double]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0.0){
            ForEach(0..<self.amplitudes.count, id: \.self) { number in
                VerticalBar(amplitude: self.$amplitudes[number])
            }
            .drawingGroup()
        }
    }
    
}
```

and `VerticalBar.swift`

```
/// Single bar of Amplitude Visualizer
struct VerticalBar: View {
    
    @Binding var amplitude: Double
    
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader
                { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
    
                    // Colored rectangle in back of ZStack
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .yellow, .green]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .center))
    
                        // blue/purple bar style - try switching this out with the .fill statement above
                        //.fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.init(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0), .blue, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    
                    // Dynamic black mask padded from bottom in relation to the amplitude
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.black)
                        .mask(Rectangle().padding(.bottom, geometry.size.height * CGFloat(self.amplitude)))
                        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.05))
    
                    // White bar with slower animation for floating effect
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.005)
                        .offset(x: 0.0, y: -geometry.size.height * CGFloat(self.amplitude) - geometry.size.height * 0.02)
                        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.6))
    
                }
                .padding(geometry.size.width * 0.1)
                .border(Color.black, width: geometry.size.width * 0.1)
            }.drawingGroup()
        }
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue, any fixes?

Comment: you will have to draw on the GPU is my guess 
Metal it is